# Removing coefficients and repeated elements

Tags: list-manipulation

I got to a problem where as I just can't find the proper *Mathematica* command.

I'm given a list, for example:

$\{1,x1,-x1,x2,x5,x3,-x2,-x4\}$

I need this to become

$\{1,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5\}$

The example is just a small possibility with all $x_i$ present. There's only 1 variable at all times. $X =Array[x,6]$

A second example to be more clear. I'll make it a little bit more terrifying:
$\{1,x_1,-x_1,x_2,x_5,x_3,-4x_2,-x_4,-1,x_1x_2,-x_3x_5,x_6^2\}$

needs to become

$\{1,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_1x_2,x_3x_5,x_6^2\}$

Comment: DeleteDuplicates would probably be the place to start.  You will likely have to use the second argument to the function since you want to count -x1 and x1 as duplicates.

Comment: It would be more clear if the examples were written as *Mathematica* code. Does $x_1$ mean `x1`, `x[1]` or `Subscript[x,1]` ?

Answer (score 7):

Going by the input and output as shown in the question I believe you want [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Union.html).  For example:

```
list = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -x2, -x4};

Union[list /. -x_ :> x]
```

> ```
> {1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
> ```

You did say "There's only 1 variable at all times." Understand that in *Mathematica* `x1` and `x2` are separate Symbols.  Possibly you want:

```
list = {1, x 1, -x 1, x 2, x 5, x 3, -x 2, -x 4};

Union[list /. x_*n_?Negative :> -n x]
```

> ```
> {1, x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x}
> ```

Or:

```
Union[ Abs[list] /. Abs[n_] :> n ]
```

> ```
> {1, x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x}
> ```

---

This is the input form for your second example as I interpret it:

```
list2 = {1, x[1], -x[1], x[2], x[5], x[3], -4 x[2], -x[4], -1, x[1] x[2], -x[3] x[5], x[6]^2};
```

If this is incorrect please let me know.

Applying the above method:

```
Union[Abs[list2] /. Abs[n_] :> n]
```

> ```
> {1, x[1], x[2], 4 x[2], x[1] x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[3] x[5], x[6]^2}
> ```

We have both `x[2]` and `4 x[2]` which is not shown in your output.  The reason for that is not clear to me.  Should all coefficients be stripped?  Perhaps:

```
Union[list2 /. {-1 -> 1, _?NumericQ*x[n_] :> x[n]}] ~SortBy~ Length
```

> ```
> {1, x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[1] x[2], x[3] x[5], x[6]^2}
> ```

This still has `x[5]` which your target does not.  I don't know why that would be eliminated by not `x[3]` so I am assuming it is a mistake.

Comment: Nice is quite looking like, it didn't mention that it could also become -1 , is it easy to change that to 1?

Comment: @Jban Do you mean you may have `{1, . . ., -1, . . .}` and you want to keep only `1`?

Comment: Its more like x= {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6...xn} That's my only variable, next to them there are all constants positive and negative of which I need all abs's but, abs fails at variables. If you know what I mean...

Comment: @Jban Did you see the update to my answer?  If that doesn't apply, please give me a *specific* example and I'll try to address it.

Comment: I updated my question to become more clear.

Comment: Coefficients should be stripped but I didn't see that as my main problem therefore I keot that to myself, but now we are invstigating it more i thought it was aklso wise to add this to the example. The input is correct and the final output also.

Comment: @Jban I took another crack at this.  I have to leave now but if I didn't get it right I'll be happy to try again later.

Answer (score 4):

```
array = {1, y1, -y1, y2, y5, y3, -y2, -y4}    
DeleteCases[array, Times[-1, _]]
{1, y1, y2, y5, y3}
```

If it were possible to have two of any "positive" element in the array like:

```
array = {1, y1, -y1, y2, y5, y3, -y2, -y4, y5}
```

You could remove them by using DeleteDuplicates[]:

```
DeleteDuplicates[DeleteCases[array, Times[-1, _]]]
{1, y1, y2, y5, y3}
```

Comment: It's almost that what I need, because the $-x_4$ is also deleted, when i still needed it. Thnx allready

Answer (score 4):

You could use a replacement rule to change all the negatives to positives, followed by DeleteDuplicates[].

```
array = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -x2, -x4}
DeleteDuplicates[array /. Times[-1, x_] -> x]
```

> {1, x1, x2, x5, x3, x4}

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach that may already be implicit in one or more of the other answers, but I think it should be made explicit.

```
data1 = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -x2, -x4};
data2 = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -4 x2, -x4, -1, x1 x2, -x3 x5, x6^2};

f[data_List] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[data /. {Times[_Integer, x_] -> x, x_Integer?Negative -> -x}]

f[data1]
f[data2]
```

> {1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}
>   {1, x1, x2, x1 x2, x3, x4, x5, x3 x5, x6^2}

#### Edit

As Mike Honeychurch suggests, if it's not clear how this works, you should take a look at the full form of data2.

```
data2 // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[
>    1, x1, Times[-1, x1], x2, x5, x3, Times[-4, x2], Times[-1, x4], -1, 
>    Times[x1, x2], Times[-1, x3, x5], Power[x6, 2]
>  ]
> ```

This shows that the primary problem is to deal with expressions of the form `Times[_Integer, x_]`. These are handled by the first rule in the `ReplaceAll` expression

```
data /. {Times[_Integer, x_] -> x, x_Integer?Negative -> -x}
```

There is a secondary problem of dealing with negative integer constants. These are handled by the second rule.

Comment: Might be worth adding a copy of `FullForm[data2]` to help him visualize what is occurring ...for own learning benefit etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SubsetCases`:

```
list1 = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -x2, -x4};
list2 = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -4 x2, -x4, -1, x1 x2, -x3 x5, x6^2};

r1 = -1 -> 1;
r2 = {c_?NumericQ*x_ | x_ z_.} :> Union@{x, x z};

SortBy[Length]@*Union@*Join @@ SubsetCases[# /. r1, r2] &@list1

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}*)

SortBy[Length]@*Union@*Join @@ SubsetCases[# /. r1, r2] &@list2

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x1 x2, x3 x5, x6^2}*)
```

Or using a single rule with `SubsetCases`:

```
rule = {c_?NumberQ*x_ | x_ z_.} :> If[NumberQ[x], Abs[x], Sequence @@ {x, x z}];

SortBy[Length]@*Union@SubsetCases[#, rule] &@list1

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}*)

SortBy[Length]@*Union@SubsetCases[#, rule] &@list2

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x1 x2, x3 x5, x6^2}*)
```

Another possibility is to use `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules` as follows:

```
rep = Rule[x_, y_] /; y =!= 1 :> Rule[x, 1];

r1 = CoefficientRules[#, Variables[#]] &@# &@list1 /. rep;

SortBy[Length]@*Union@(FromCoefficientRules[#, Variables[list1]] & /@ r1)

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}*)

r2 = CoefficientRules[#, Variables[#]] &@# &@list2 /. rep;

SortBy[Length]@*Union@(FromCoefficientRules[#, Variables[list2]] & /@ r2)

(*{1, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x1 x2, x3 x5, x6^2}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {1, x1, -x1, x2, x5, x3, -x2, -x4, -8, -x6^2};

Union @ ReplaceAll[a_ /; MatchQ[ToBoxes[a], RowBox[{"-", __}]] :> -a] @ list
```

{1, 8, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6^2}